# Function overload ambiguous with type covariance but not ambiguous with generic

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have the following code.

```kotlin
open class Parent
class Child: Parent()

fun <T: Parent> foo(obj: T): T = obj
inline fun <T: Parent> foo(block: () -> T): T = foo(block())

fun <T> bar(obj: T): T = obj
inline fun <T> bar(block: () -> T): T = bar(block())

fun main() {
    /* Compile error:
    Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
        public inline fun <T : Parent> foo (block: () → TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T) defined in examples in file example.kt
        public fun <T : Parent> foo (obj: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T) defined in examples in file example.kt
     */
    foo { Child() }

    // Works
    bar { "something" }
}
```

The first function call (`foo`) gives me a compilation error saying the overload resolution is ambiguous. But why is this true since the block is of type `() -> T` and this isn't a subtype of `Parent`?

Shouldn't this error occur on the second function call (`bar`)? Why doesn't it occur?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem here is with type inference. In each of your examples, you're relying on type inference for two things:

1. To determine the value of the generic type parameter `T`, and
2. To determine the signature of the lambda function.

In the case of `foo`, the overload resolution depends on knowing the value of the generic parameter `T`. That's because `T` is bounded. The actual value of `T` might affect whether it's valid to call this method or not, depending on whether `T` turns out to be a subtype of `Parent`.

The problem is that `T` needs to be inferred based on the value of the parameter being passed in, and the type of the parameter being passed in needs to be inferred based on some information about which overload has been selected and/or what the value of `T` is! I suspect this creates a circular dependency that prevents the overload resolution from completing.

You can fix it by providing a value either for the lambda signature or for the generic type parameter:

```kotlin
foo<Parent> { Child() } // works
foo({ Child() } as () -> Parent) // works
```

Extracting the lambda to a variable fixes it too, because it makes the compiler infer a type for the variable straight away:

```kotlin
val lambda = { Child() } // type is inferred as () -> Child
foo(lambda) // works, because lambda already has an inferred type
```

The problem doesn't arise with `bar` because in that case, `T` is unbounded. No matter what `T` ends up being, it won't affect whether that particular overload is allowed to be called or not. That means the compiler doesn't need to infer a value for `T` before performing overload resolution.

Comment: Overload resolution is not only about the possibility of a method call, but also about [choosing the most specific candidate](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#choosing-the-most-specific-candidate-from-the-overload-candidate-set), so type inference is [always performed](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/overload-resolution.html#description) before overload resolution _for every non-lambda argument of the function. Lambda arguments are excluded, as their type inference needs the results of overload resolution to finish._

Comment: _Note: this is valid even if `T` is a free type variable without any explicit constraints, as every type in Kotlin has an implicit constraint `kotlin.Nothing <: T <: kotlin.Any?`_

Comment: By the way, if the type for `bar` functions was defined with an explicit constraint `T : Any` it would still worked

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug(s) in the compiler (still present in 1.6.0-M1).

Two workarounds here:

1. Explicitly specify type argument:

```kotlin
foo<Child> { Child() }
```

Ironically, doing the same with the working part will break it (but the error won't be about ambiguity, the compiler is pretty sure what overload he's gonna call - the wrong one):

```kotlin
/* Compile error:
Type mismatch.
   Required: () → String
   Found: String
*/
bar<() -> String>({ "something" })
```

2. Extract lambda into a separate variable:

```kotlin
val lambda = { Child() }
foo(lambda)
```

This will fix the broken part as well:

```
val block = { "something" }
bar<() -> String>(block)
```

Comment: The type on the second block of code is wrong, it would be `bar<String>({ "something" })`

Comment: Yes, probably, you're initial intention was this (then you'll get a second overload), but it's perfectly legal to specify `() -> String` type as well (in order to get a first one)

Comment: Ya but the intention is to the get the second one

Comment: My point is that the compiler should handle both cases correctly.
If the type was explicitly specified as `String` and there was passed an argument of `() -> String` type, then ambiguity should have been resolved in favor of the second overload (because the first would have required argument of `String` type). If the type was explicitly specified as `() -> String` and there was  passed an argument of `() -> String` type, then - in favor of the first one (because the second would have required argument of `() -> () -> String` type).